# How can anchor tags (for internal links) be put into a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, anchor, internal-link

I have a long alphabetical list to be displayed by a gridview.

I need to have links at the top of the page that will link to anchors in the gridview. How can I get anchor tags in the gridview so that the links will jump to them when clicked?

Note: Paging is not an option

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the GridView's ClientIDMode to `Static` or `Predictable`(if using Framework 4.0) to avoid ASP.Net generating unique names according to their NamingContainers(GridViewRow). You should ensure that the ID's are unique by yourself from RowDataBound(f.e. append an identifier).

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)
- http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/understanding-clientidmodepredictable.html

If you are using Framework < 4.0 you have to generate the HyperLink's NavigateUrl from RowDataBound of the GridView via the ClientID of your link targets.

Comment: I can't just put the hyperlink in there as part of the "data" in the cell, i.e. straight from the database `<a name=""L""></a>`?

Comment: Ok . . . I actually got it to work. I just pulled the hyperlink from the database and it works ok. It wasn't working before because it was on a "hidden" column. But I don't understand why it would not work just because the column was hidden. In the source of the page I can clearly see the anchor (albiet on the hidden column). Any ideas?

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: have to looked at the html-source? You should post an example what's being generated from asp.net in your gridview and also from your top-links. Edit: What do you mean with `hidden`? If it was `Visible="false"` it wouldn't have been generated at all.

Comment: @Tim: The top-links are just hard coded. I have looked at the html-source. The anchors are there, they just aren't "working". They are in a hidden column, but still . . . they are in the source, so shouldn't they work? As soon as I made the column visible, the anchors started working . . .

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: again, when you have not made the column invisible via CSS but on serverside with Visible-Property, it won't be rendered on clientside at all. So what do you mean with `hidden column`? Also, if you make it Visible="False" the grid will not bind data to the column at all. Edit: thanks for accepting, the important thing is it works :)

Comment: @Tim: When I say "hidden", I mean that in the design-time settings, I set that column's "Hidden" property to true.

Comment: @Richard: if it's the issue i think(data not bound on invisible column), try to set it to visible on design time but hide it in [RowCreated-event-handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) because that comes later than `RowDataBound`: `e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a name="anchor1">Text</a> 

Link to anchor: <a href="#anchor1">Link</a>
```

Comment: For some reason that's not working for me. I tried that. I put the anchor `<a name="anchor1">Text</a>` in one of the cells, and it still doesn't jump to the anchor.

Comment: Could you give the complete HTML, use e.g. https://gist.github.com/ to paste the code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. There is a lot of sensitive data in there. And there is a LOT of it . . . way too much to strip out. Sorry.